# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

The terminal stop with message:

> "can't load DistUpgradeViewGt3 (No module named 'DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeViewGt3')

How do I solve this problem?

---

Edit:

I installed python and ran upgrade again but the process aborts with a list of packages that could not be safely installed.

An upgrade-window opened to support me, but disappeared when I had to use it. Do I have to give up upgrading Ubuntu?

Comment: this should be on [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 2):

Sharing the same question asked on askubuntu with the provided answer, in case somebody googles this

> Before running upgrade you have to reinstall the related package by
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-distupgrade`
>
> Note: if you have errors while running sudo apt-get update command -
> then please add them to your question by editing it.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1360562